# Is it possible to create a recursive dataclass using make_dataclass in python?

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

Here is a simple example where I am trying to create a recursive Node definition which contains an optional child that is also a Node. The code compiles but when I try to access the type definitions I get `node` is not defined. Is it possible to get around this error?

```py
import dataclasses
import typing as t

node_type = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
    "node", [("child", t.Optional["node"], dataclasses.field(default=None))]
)
print(t.get_type_hints(node_type))
```

Outputs

```sh
NameError: name 'node' is not defined
```

I'm using python 3.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems here. They're solvable, but they may not be cleanly solvable in the kinds of situations where you would actually use `dataclasses.make_dataclass`.

The first problem is that `typing.get_type_hints` is looking for a class named `'node'`, but you called the global variable `node_type`. The name you pass to `make_dataclass`, the name you use in the annotations, and the name you assign the dataclass to all have to be the same:

```
Node = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
    "Node", [("child", t.Optional["Node"], dataclasses.field(default=None))]
)
```

But that's still not going to be enough, because `typing.get_type_hints` isn't looking in the right namespace. That's the second problem.

When you call `typing.get_type_hints` on a class, `typing.get_type_hints` will try to resolve string annotations by looking in the module where the class was defined. It determines that module by looking at the `__module__` entry in the class's `__dict__`. Because you've created your node class in a weird way that doesn't go through the normal `class` statement, the class's `__module__` isn't set up to refer to the right module. Instead, it's set to `'types'`.

You can fix this by manually pre-setting `__module__` to the `__name__` of the current module:

```
Node = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
    "Node",
    [("child", t.Optional["Node"], dataclasses.field(default=None))],
    namespace={'__module__': __name__}
)
```

Then `typing.get_type_hints` will be able to resolve the string annotations.

The meta-problem is, if you're using `dataclasses.make_dataclass` in practice, you probably don't know the class name. You're probably using it in a function, and/or inside a loop. `typing.get_type_hints` has to be able to find the class through a global variable matching the class name, but dynamic variable names are messy.

You can take the simple approach of just setting a global with `globals()`:

```
globals()[your_dataclass.__name__] = your_dataclass
```

but that's dangerous. If two generated classes have the same name, the second will replace the first. If a generated class has the same name as something else in the global namespace, such as if you did `from some_dependency import Thing` and then generated a class named `Thing`, the generated class will stomp the existing global value.

If you can guarantee those things won't happen, `globals()` might be fine. If you can't make such guarantees, you might need to do something like generate a new module for each generated class to live in, so they each get their own independent global namespace, or you might just accept and document the fact that `get_type_hints` won't work for your generated classes.

Comment: ok this is very comprehensive and most definitely the correct answer. I'm using this syntax to dynamically create classes at runtime that have proper type annotations, and the class name is unknown at runtime. Is it possible to dynamically set the name I assign the dataclass to? For example I don't know ahead of time that the variable will be called Node.

Comment: Nevermind my comment. I can just use `globals()`.

Comment: @LukeMurray: Note that that relies on no two classes created this way having the same name, and no class names ever colliding with a name you're already using in that global scope.